# Non-linear ODE $1+y'^2=yy'^2$, $y(0)=b,y(a)=c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

How to solve
$$1+y'^2=yy'^2?$$
The initial condition is $y(0)=b,y(a)=c$.

It is a non-linear ODE.

Some hint is also helpful! Thanks for your help!

Comment: One can integrate directly $\sqrt{y-1}y'=\pm1$ to $(y-1)^{3/2}=\pm\frac32 t+C$, that is, $y(t)=1+\sqrt[3]{(C\pm\frac32t)^2}$, or simply, changing the value of $C$, $y(t)=1+\sqrt[3]{(\frac32t+c)^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$1+(y')^2=y(y')^2$$
Divide by $(y')^2$ to get $$\frac{1}{(y')^2}=y-1$$

Let us solve for $x=x(y)$ instead of for $y=y(x)$. Then we get the equation:
$$x'=\sqrt{y-1}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{We need to do the other sign of the square root too.}$$

Separate variables now: $$\begin{align}dx&=\sqrt{y-1}dy\\x+C&=\frac{2}{3}(y-1)^{3/2}\\y&=\left[\frac{3}{2}(x+C)\right]^{2/3}+1\end{align}$$

And we need to check which of these solutions do satisfy the original equation.

Comment: Thanks for your clever answer! I have a question, how we get $x'=\sqrt {y-1}$?

Comment: @Sherry $x=x(y)$ is the inverse function of $y=y(x)$. Use the derivative of the inverse function $x'=\frac{1}{y'}$.